# os.rename(source, destination) The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, operating-system, file-rename

```
import os

f = open("Names.txt", "r") 
names = f.readlines()

folder = r'C:\Users\e007l\Desktop\Rename\\'

count = 1

for file_name in os.listdir(folder):
    source = folder + file_name
    destination = folder + names[int(count)] + ".txt"
    os.rename(source, destination)
    count += 1
    res = os.listdir(folder)

print(res)
print(folder)
```

This is should change the names of the files in the folder to the names in my list but it won't it simply gives me the error message:

[WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\Path\names1.txt' -> 'C:\Path\Beta\n.txt'

My text file Names.txt has this inside:

Alpha Beta Delta Omega

Those are the names I want to Give to the existing files

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 errors:

1. The names are not loaded currectly;
2. The paths of the files are not join correctly;
3. You start your count at 1, so it throws an Index error.

Here is a code that seems to work in the way you want.

```py
import os

f = open("Names.txt", "r")
names = f.readline().split(' ')
print(f"{names = }")

folder = r'.\rename'

for i, file_name in enumerate(os.listdir(folder)):
    source = os.path.join(folder, file_name)
    destination = os.path.join(folder, names[i]) + ".txt"
    os.rename(source, destination)

res = os.listdir(folder)

print(res)
print(folder)
```

Output:

```
names = ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Delta', 'Omega']
['Alpha.txt', 'Beta.txt', 'Delta.txt']
.\rename
```